# How to efficiently perform load and bitwise operation using GPGPU?

Tags: c, cuda, bit-manipulation, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I need to load an array of 128 to 256 bytes length to GPU shared memory.

I want to minimize global memory access while performing bit-wise operations efficiently.

I have a 256 byte array loaded to global memory and I want load all the 256 bytes to shared memory at the beginning of the kernel code.

Then, on each byte a bit-wise operation has to be performed while this operation can apply on two 1 byte variables, two 2 byte variables or two 4 byte variables and bigger.

The questions are:

1. If I load the 16 bytes of the array per thread then I have just one memory access for (warp size)*(16bytes) data or the best way is 4 bytes per thread?
2. If I load 16 bytes per thread into shared memory then will I OR these 16 bytes with a same 16 bytes variable to set a bit to 1?
3. If I load 16 bytes per thread then perform an OR operation on a 16 bytes data type, is it faster to use a 4 byte data type or smaller?

For example I want to set the 3rd bit to `1`:

```
__shared__ (which data type?) temp = ((which data type?) *)array[i];
temp |= (a variable with third bit set to 1)
```

`array` is in global memory and I want to load it to shared memory by the minimum amount of global memory accesses.

Comment: Do you really need shared memory? (Are you reusing `temp` throughout your kernel, or storing the result immediately back to global?) If yes, use whatever size you configured your shared memory banks to use (default is 4 bytes). Lower than that will get you suboptimal performance (no point doing 4 ORs on 1 byte at a time when you can do 1 OR on 4 bytes simultaneously), higher than that will get you bank conflicts. So, assuming your banks are at the 4-bytes default, use an `uint32_t` for the bitwise operations.

Comment: Yes I need because the bytes that is loaded by a thread may use with other threads. I need to perform bitwise operation on one byte of the loaded data to shared memory. Therefor, I want to know how can load the data to shared memory with minimum memory access and perform bitwise operations on thess bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the size of the memory transaction to the bank size.  Most of the time, the bank size is 32-bits.  Starting with Kepler, you could specify a bank size of 64 bits by calling `cudaDeviceSharedMemConfig()`

Acceleware has a good resource on the topic:

http://acceleware.com/blog/maximizing-shared-memory-bandwidth-nvidia-kepler-gpus